# Azure IOT Edge module repository name must be lowercase

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Azure issues with deploying to raspberry pi 4. `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.EdgeletCommunicationException- Message:Error calling Create module camera-capture: Could not create module camera-capture caused by: Could not pull image ${MODULES.CameraCapture.arm32v7}:latest caused by: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase, StatusCode:500,at: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.Version_2019_01_30.ModuleManagementHttpClient.HandleException(Exception exception, String operation) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-`

I have no idea what needs to be lowercase I have tried changing a lot of my deployment to be lowercase and didn't work.

```
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {
              "registryName": {
                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME",
                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD",
                "address": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": ""
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
              "createOptions": ""
            },
            "env": {
                "OptimizeForPerformance": {
                  "value": "false"
                }
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "camera-capture": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "env": {
              "VIDEO_PATH": {"value": "0"},
              "IMAGE_PROCESSING_ENDPOINT":  {"value": "http://image-classifier-service:80/image"},
              "RESIZE_WIDTH":  {"value": "256"},
              "RESIZE_HEIGHT":  {"value": "256"},
              "SHOW_VIDEO":  {"value": "True"}
            },
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.CameraCapture.arm32v7}",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"5012/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"5012\"}]},\"Binds\":[\"/dev/video0:/dev/video0\"],\"Devices\":[{\"PathOnHost\":\"/dev/video0\",\"PathInContainer\":\"/dev/video0\",\"CgroupPermissions\":\"mrw\"}]}}"
            }
          },
          "image-classifier-service": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.ImageClassifierService.arm32v7}",
              "createOptions": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "routes": {
          "CameraCaptureToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/camera-capture/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream",
          "CameraCaptureGAToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/CameraCaptureGA/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi. Anyone have a similar issue with lowercase (I think it is docker related). Any help would be great!

Docker Version:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 2
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 6
 Server Version: 19.03.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.97-v7l+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.764GiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: XVOF:57EL:VCLC:2JZH:L4ON:OFXK:3DBO:FTPO:Z56Q:LID2:RD7P:THEV
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Answer (score 0):

You image property on the module camera-capture is invalid. The repository name should be in lowercase, as states the error message "Could not pull image ${MODULES.CameraCapture.arm32v7}:latest caused by: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase".

```
          "image": "${MODULES.CameraCapture.arm32v7}",
```

You should confirm the location of your image, and use lowercase

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for taking a look at this, I have tried changing the "image" to
```"image": "${modules.imageclassifierservice.arm32v7}",```
but I get 
```caused by: Could not pull image ${modules.cameracapture.arm32v7}:latest
 caused by: invalid reference format, StatusCode:500```
and with 
```${MODULES.imageclassifierservice.arm32v7}``` I get the same error as before. Guessing that is what you meant by lowecase?

Comment: Yes Peter, but now you need to be sure that the reference to your image is correct. it looks like it is not.

Comment: How do you deploy the edge solution to the edge device ?  
Is the first snippet that you've posted a deployment.json file or a deployment.template.json file ?  It looks like a mixed up version of both ?